# How to refresh FaceBook Graph API data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Every time I make a change to the graph api metas like add/remove users from `fb:admins`, I see that the changes are not taking place until I call the flowing URL:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=

My question is what is the correct way to do a refresh? Should I call(pragmatically) this URL every time that I make a  change? Or may be there is another dedicated API to do the refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/), you can trigger a scrape of object by hitting the endpoint of

```
POST /?id={object-instance-id or object-url}&scrape=true
```

Additionally, Facebook will scrape the object once a week no matter what.

Comment: I am new to FB and not sure what URL I suppose to call, it doesn't specify the URL only the params?

Comment: Almost everything concerning the Graph API is handled using the URL http[s]://graph.facebook.com/