# Graph-API: How-to refresh share attachment of post?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website which automaticaly post links in several facebook pages. It has worked fine until yesterday, when the first link posted doesn't take the image from metas:

```
og:image
og:image:secure_url
og:image:width
og:image:height
```

In the second page and followings are ok.

To take the image I should go to post page and refresh the share attachment manually.

I've tested scraping the link at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and it seems correct.

Also I've seen at [How to refresh FaceBook Graph API data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421078/how-to-refresh-facebook-graph-api-data) to scrape again the page but the problem it's not to scrape the page but refresh the share attachment:

[image: contextual menu of post]

Anybody knows how to refresh the image of link posted through the Graph API of Facebook?

I just want to request the "Refresh share attachment" action of post.

Thanks for yours answers.

P.S.: English it's not my motherlanguage.

Comment: No possible. That has to be done via the UI. (Obvious reason: You don’t want me to change that “oh look those cute little kittens” link I made you post yesterday into “cheap v14gr4 h3re” today, and have that change automatically reflected on your timeline ...)

Comment: Ok, and how can I force FB to take the good content  with image at first post?

Comment: @CBroe that's a very weak argument. If I can refresh the share attachment via the UI, since I'm the business owner, why can't I refresh that share attachment via the API, using a token that still identifies my business and ownership of both the Facebook page and URL posted?

Comment: @luqita probably because Facebook did not consider this edge case worth implementing to begin with; remember, this is from a time when posting stuff to user profiles was also still possible and probably the major use case, compared to posting on the pages someone admins ...

Comment: Any updates on this? I am struggling with the same issue. I already have publishing permission but having to delete the old post and publish again causes lost comments and likes...

Comment: @cerkiner Unfortunately the only way is to refresh share attachment manually. But I've avoided the matter of take the good attachment at first post scraping the url before publishing ( see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/url/#update )

Comment: any updates on that?

Comment: Have you tried adding 'scrape' => 'true' to your payload ? that will scrape the post's metadata and refresh the share attachment. give it some time to propagate aswell. :)